Swift UI view not clickable
I have a stacked cards view that interact like an iPhone's notifications. Each element is not clickable unless it's fading out (not completely to scale and not fully hidden). Why isn't each rectangle clickable? There is no overlay so I'm not sure why I can't interact with the views.
Copy paste-able code:
import SwiftUI

struct HomeMain2: View {
    var body: some View {
        StackedCardsNew(items: itemsC, stackedDisplayCount: 1, opacityDisplayCount: 1, itemHeight: 70) { item in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        }
        .safeAreaPadding(.bottom, 80)
        .safeAreaPadding(15)
    }
}

struct StackedCardsNew<Content: View, Data: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Data.Element: Identifiable {
    var items: Data
    var stackedDisplayCount: Int = 2
    var opacityDisplayCount: Int = 2
    var disablesOpacityEffect: Bool = false
    var spacing: CGFloat = 5
    var itemHeight: CGFloat
    @ViewBuilder var content: (Data.Element) -> Content
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            let topPadding: CGFloat = size.height - itemHeight
            
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: spacing) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Button {
                            //can't click this button
                        } label: {
                            content(item)
                        }
                        .frame(height: itemHeight)
                        .visualEffect { content, geometryProxy in
                            content
                                .opacity(disablesOpacityEffect ? 1 : opacity(geometryProxy))
                                .scaleEffect(scale(geometryProxy), anchor: .bottom)
                                .offset(y: offset(geometryProxy))
                        }
                        .zIndex(zIndex(item))
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .safeAreaPadding(.top, topPadding)
        }
    }

    func headerOffset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy, _ topPadding: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let viewSize = proxy.size.height - itemHeight
        
        return -minY > (topPadding - viewSize) ? -viewSize : -minY - topPadding
    }
    func zIndex(_ item: Data.Element) -> Double {
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) as? Int {
            return Double(items.count) - Double(index)
        }
        
        return 0
    }
    func offset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let progress = minY / itemHeight
        let maxOffset = CGFloat(stackedDisplayCount) * offsetForEachItem
        let offset = max(min(progress * offsetForEachItem, maxOffset), 0)
        
        return minY < 0 ? 0 : -minY + offset
    }
    func scale(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let progress = minY / itemHeight
        let maxScale = CGFloat(stackedDisplayCount) * scaleForEachItem
        let scale = max(min(progress * scaleForEachItem, maxScale), 0)
        
        return 1 - scale
    }
    func opacity(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let progress = minY / itemHeight
        let opacityForItem = 1 / CGFloat(opacityDisplayCount + 1)
        
        let maxOpacity = CGFloat(opacityForItem) * CGFloat(opacityDisplayCount + 1)
        let opacity = max(min(progress * opacityForItem, maxOpacity), 0)
        
        return progress < CGFloat(opacityDisplayCount + 1) ? 1 - opacity : 0
    }
    var offsetForEachItem: CGFloat { return 8 }
    var scaleForEachItem: CGFloat { return 0.08 }
}

// IGNORE

struct ItemC: Identifiable{
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var logo: String
    var title: String
    var description: String = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
}

var itemsC: [ItemC] = [
    ItemC(logo: "", title: ""),
    ItemC(logo: "Amazon", title: "Amazon"),
    ItemC(logo: "Youtube", title: "Youtube"),
    ItemC(logo: "Dribbble", title: "Dribbble"),
    ItemC(logo: "Apple", title: "Apple"),
    ItemC(logo: "Patreon", title: "Patreon"),
    ItemC(logo: "Instagram", title: "Instagram"),
    ItemC(logo: "Netflix", title: "Netflix"),
    ItemC(logo: "Photoshop", title: "Photoshop"),
    ItemC(logo: "Figma", title: "Figma")
]

#Preview {
    HomeMain2()
}


I think the issue is caused by .safeAreaPadding(.top, topPadding) and .offset(y: offset(geometryProxy)). It seems that all taps above topPadding are ignored.
So, the workaround is to put your buttons lower in ScrollView by adding topPadding to offset(geometryProxy): .offset(y: offset(geometryProxy)  + topPadding). Also I added Color.clear.frame(height: topPadding) to give scroll view some space for scrolling.
Here is the full code updated:
import SwiftUI

struct HomeMain2: View {
    var body: some View {
        StackedCardsNew(items: itemsC, stackedDisplayCount: 1, opacityDisplayCount: 1, itemHeight: 70) { item in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
        }
        .safeAreaPadding(.bottom, 80)
        .safeAreaPadding(15)
    }
}

struct StackedCardsNew<Content: View, Data: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Data.Element: Identifiable {
    var items: Data
    var stackedDisplayCount: Int = 2
    var opacityDisplayCount: Int = 2
    var disablesOpacityEffect: Bool = false
    var spacing: CGFloat = 5
    var itemHeight: CGFloat
    @ViewBuilder var content: (Data.Element) -> Content
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            let topPadding: CGFloat = size.height - itemHeight
            
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: spacing) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Button {
                            // now you can click
                        } label: {
                            content(item)
                        }
                        .frame(height: itemHeight)
                        .visualEffect { content, geometryProxy in
                            content
                                .opacity(disablesOpacityEffect ? 1 : opacity(geometryProxy))
                                .scaleEffect(scale(geometryProxy), anchor: .bottom)
                            // Added "+ topPadding" to get the same screen position of the elements
                                .offset(y: offset(geometryProxy)  + topPadding)
                        }
                        .zIndex(zIndex(item))
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
                // Added some placeholder for corrrect scroll behavior
                Color.clear
                    .frame(height: topPadding)
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        }
    }
// Nothing is changed below this line 
    func headerOffset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy, _ topPadding: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let viewSize = proxy.size.height - itemHeight
        
        return -minY > (topPadding - viewSize) ? -viewSize : -minY - topPadding
    }
    func zIndex(_ item: Data.Element) -> Double {
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) as? Int {
            return Double(items.count) - Double(index)
        }
        
        return 0
    }
    func offset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let progress = minY / itemHeight
        let maxOffset = CGFloat(stackedDisplayCount) * offsetForEachItem
        let offset = max(min(progress * offsetForEachItem, maxOffset), 0)
        
        return minY < 0 ? 0 : -minY + offset
    }
    func scale(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let progress = minY / itemHeight
        let maxScale = CGFloat(stackedDisplayCount) * scaleForEachItem
        let scale = max(min(progress * scaleForEachItem, maxScale), 0)
        
        return 1 - scale
    }
    func opacity(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
        let progress = minY / itemHeight
        let opacityForItem = 1 / CGFloat(opacityDisplayCount + 1)
        
        let maxOpacity = CGFloat(opacityForItem) * CGFloat(opacityDisplayCount + 1)
        let opacity = max(min(progress * opacityForItem, maxOpacity), 0)
        
        return progress < CGFloat(opacityDisplayCount + 1) ? 1 - opacity : 0
    }
    var offsetForEachItem: CGFloat { return 8 }
    var scaleForEachItem: CGFloat { return 0.08 }
}

// IGNORE

struct ItemC: Identifiable{
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var logo: String
    var title: String
    var description: String = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
}

var itemsC: [ItemC] = [
    ItemC(logo: "", title: ""),
    ItemC(logo: "Amazon", title: "Amazon"),
    ItemC(logo: "Youtube", title: "Youtube"),
    ItemC(logo: "Dribbble", title: "Dribbble"),
    ItemC(logo: "Apple", title: "Apple"),
    ItemC(logo: "Patreon", title: "Patreon"),
    ItemC(logo: "Instagram", title: "Instagram"),
    ItemC(logo: "Netflix", title: "Netflix"),
    ItemC(logo: "Photoshop", title: "Photoshop"),
    ItemC(logo: "Figma", title: "Figma")
]

#Preview {
    HomeMain2()
}


Hey can you please help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78910368/ignoring-safe-area-prevents-button-click
